# Update by LEAD/LAG or Recursive CTE?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

There is a table holding date and account balance.
However, the balance is not available for some dates.
Assuming the balance does not change when date is unavailable.
How to update the balance information for all dates?

Here is an example:
Table D contains all valid dates.

```
2000-01-01
2000-01-02
2000-01-03
2000-01-04
2000-01-05
2000-01-06
2000-01-07
2000-01-08
2000-01-09
```

Table A contains date and account balance.

```
2000-01-02  $100
2000-01-05  $200
2000-01-09  $700
```

Ultimately, I want to generate a table like this:

```
2000-01-01  null
2000-01-02  $100
2000-01-03  $100
2000-01-04  $100
2000-01-05  $200
2000-01-06  $200
2000-01-07  $200
2000-01-08  $200
2000-01-09  $700
```

I have thought about the following:

- LEAD and LAG,
- Recursive CTE

However, it seems that none of them is suitable for this scenario.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? They are completely different RDBMS?

Comment: I prefer using SQL Server, but MySQL is also fine, if it doesn't involve using a MySQL-only function.

Comment: Be handy if you showed us what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not support the `IGNORE NULLS` option for `LAG()` or `LAST_VALUE()`.  That is actually the simplest method.

Instead, you can use `APPLY`:

```
select d.*, a.balance
from dates d outer apply
     (select top (1) a.*
      from a
      where a.date <= d.date
      order by a.date desc
     ) a;
```

Or the equivalent using a correlated subquery:

```
select d.*,
       (select top (1) a.*
        from a
        where a.date <= d.date
        order by a.date desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       )
from dates d;
```

This will work in both MySQL and SQL Server with the caveat that you need `LIMIT` in MySQL.

That said, if you had a large amount of data (which is unlikely at the granularity of "date"), then a two-steps of window functions are probably the better solution:

```
select ad.date,
       max(ad.balance) over (partition by grp) as balance
from (select d.date, a.balance,
             count(a.date) over (order by d.date) as grp
      from dates d left join
           a
           on d.date = a.date
     ) ad;
```

The subquery assigns a "group" to each balance value and the following dates.  This "group" is then used to assign the balance in the outer query.

This version will work in both MySQL or SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could achieve this is by using first value and creating some ranking functions. I am using SQL server

```
with cte as 
(
select '2000-01-01' as Datenew union all 
select '2000-01-02' as Datenew union all 
select '2000-01-03' as Datenew union all 
select '2000-01-04' as Datenew union all 
select '2000-01-05' as Datenew union all 
select '2000-01-06' as Datenew union all 
select '2000-01-07' as Datenew union all 
select '2000-01-08' as Datenew union all 
select '2000-01-09' as Datenew ), cte2 as (
select '2000-01-02' as DateSal, '100' as Salary union all 
select '2000-01-05' as DateSal, '200' as Salary union all 
select '2000-01-09' as DateSal, '700' as Salary ) 


select datenew, Salary = FIRST_VALUE(salary) over (partition by ranking order by datenew) from (
select datenew, salary ,  
  sum(case  when DateSal  is not null then 1 end) over (order by datenew) ranking 
    from cte c 
left join cte2 c2  on  c.Datenew = c2.DateSal ) tst 

order by  datenew
```

--Sum creates running total to create a grouping and first value ensures that we are getting the same value for the given group.

this is the output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ANSI SQL.

```
Table_D
-------
dd(field name)
-------
2000-01-01
2000-01-02
2000-01-03
2000-01-04
2000-01-05
2000-01-06
2000-01-07
2000-01-08
2000-01-09


Table_A
-------
dd(field name) cost(field name)
-------
2000-01-02  $100
2000-01-05  $200
2000-01-09  $700


select a.dd
  , (
    case when a.cost is null then min(a.cost) OVER (partition by a.cost_group ORDER BY a.dd) else a.cost end
  ) as cost
from (
    select a.dd, b.cost
      , count(b.cost) over (order by a.dd) as cost_group
    from Table_D a
    left join Table_A b on (b.dd = a.dd)
) a
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `count() over ()` window function to create different `partitions` and then `min() over ()` function to spread minimum value to that partition.

First, I have created temporary variable table to hold OP data -

```
declare @xyz table (dt date, amount int)
insert into @xyz values
('2000-01-02','100'),
('2000-01-05','200'),
('2000-01-09','700');
```

Second, I will fetch max date from above table.

```
declare @maxDT date = (select cast(max(dt) as date) from @xyz);
```

Final, first `CTE` is `recursive CTE` to create data from `2000-01-01` to `max date` store in above variable. Second `CTE` is to create partitions.

```
;with cte as (
    select cast('2000-01-01' as date) as dt
    union all
    select dateadd(day,1,cte.dt) from cte where cte.dt < @maxDT
), cte2 as (
    select cte.dt, x.amount, x.dt as dt2, count(x.dt) over (order by cte.dt) as ranking
    from cte
    left join @xyz x on x.dt = cte.dt
)
select dt, min(amount) over (partition by ranking)
from cte2;
```